# C# - If DataGridView contains searched word, export these lines to new DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, textbox, datarow

I have a DataGridView. I want to do this; I will use a textbox. After the DataGridView filling, I will fill my textbox with a word and if my DataGridView's any line contains this word, I will export these lines to a new DataGridView. Let me explain. My DataGridView looks like that;

```
              Column1                  Column2           Column3
  -------------------------------------------------------------------
         albania algeria                800               55.32
      antarctica argentina              950                         
         brazil bulgaria                25                77
        india indonesia                 30000             78.53
        argentina  iran                 18                0.01
        moldova mongolia                25854             77.50
```

And imagine that I have a textbox. Let's say I wrote Argentina in my textbox. After this operation my new DataGridView looks like that;

```
             Column1                Column2                Column3
     ------------------------------------------------------------------
      antarctica argentina            950                         
      argentina iran                  18                     0.01
```

Note: I couldn't produce any idea for it, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you really need two DataGridViews:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView2.Rows.Clear();

        var filterText = textBox1.Text;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            if (Convert.ToString(row.Cells[0].Value).Contains(filterText))
            {
                var filteredRow = (DataGridViewRow)row.Clone();

                //Copy values from one DataGridViewRow to another
                foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
                {
                    filteredRow.Cells[cell.ColumnIndex].Value = cell.Value;
                }

                dataGridView2.Rows.Add(filteredRow);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Actually we do this in current DataGridView but how can I  do after the searching if I want to get my old values?

Comment: Hi, in this case I would advise you to use a DataTable with a Binding Source. If you use it you could even use the Filter property of the Binding Source. Let me know if you want an example of that so I can update my answer accordingly. Documentation for Binding Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/bindingsource-component-overview

Comment: Hi Mr. Alexandre. Your answer works. However, you can update if you want, this can also be useful. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
ConvertGridToTable();  // Add data in Datatabledt from gridview
Clipboard.Clear();
DataObject data = new DataObject(DataFormats.Serializable, Datatabledt);
Clipboard.SetDataObject(data);
```

Now the Datatabledt is available in Clipboard which you can paste in the second gridview which you can do with this:

```
DataObject data = (DataObject)Clipboard.GetDataObject();
DataTable dt = (DataTable)data.GetData(DataFormats.Serializable);

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    dtData.ImportRow(dr);
}
dtData.AcceptChanges();
grdProgramData.DataSource = dtData;
MessageBox.Show("Data Pasted.");

private void ConvertGridToTable()
{

    if (Datatabledt.Rows.Count > 0)
    { }

    Datatabledt = dtData.Clone();

    foreach (DataGridViewRow gr in YOURGRIDVIEW.SelectedRows)
    {
        DataRow dc = Datatabledt.NewRow();
        dc["KEY-FIELD"] = Int32.Parse(gr.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
        .....
        ---you can set your conditions here on the basis of textbox value---
        Datatabledt.Rows.Add(dc);
    }
    Datatabledt.AcceptChanges();
}
```